# All status value is same then update another table status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables and their value are

`lot-master`:

```
event-id   lotid    status
1           1        Awarded
1           2        Awarded
1           3        Awarded
```

and `event-master`:

```
event-id     status
1             Open
```

If all `lot-master` status is awarded then `event-master` status update using `update` query.

Comment: So what do you want ? , it is not clear.. `If all lot-master status is awarded then event-master status update using update query` , what do you want to update then ?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store "calculated" values (from other columns). For example if you add a non-awarded lotid to event-id = 1, the event-master's status will be wrong!

Comment: lot-master status automatically awarded from user

Comment: it is not neccesary all lot-master status is Awarded......
but when all lot-master status awarded then event-master status is Awarded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still if you want to do like this then you can try like this,

```
DECLARE @Count              AS INT = 0,
        @ConditionCount     INT = 0

SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM   lot-MASTER

SELECT @ConditionCount = COUNT(1) FROM  lot-MASTER WHERE  STATUS = 'Awarded'

IF (@ConditionCount = @Count)
BEGIN
    UPDATE EVENT-MASTER
    SET    STATUS = 'Awarded'
END
```